# Send S3 avro files to Kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis

I'm very new to this so I ask. Every hour I receive .avro files in my S3 bucket. I need to push these files to Kinesis stream in order to build Flink Application on top.
I was trying to use DMS where Source endpoint is S3 and Target endpoint is my Kinesis stream. However, I cannot establish Source due to this error:

`SYSTEM ERROR MESSAGE:Endpoint with s3 engine as source needs a well formed JSON for externalTableDefinition.`

What exactly should i specify in this parameter? Are there any other parameters that should be specified to enable this integration?

Comment: Can you share what you've configured for the `externalTableDefinition` parameter? Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.S3.html

Comment: I haven't configured anything as I'm not sure what i should specify. In the link you've shared it's said that the files should be in .csv format, which is not my case unfortunately. My original files are in .avro format.